# Не работает функция по замене строк на другие

Tags: python, pandas

можете подсказать, почему не работает функция?:

Есть список list_data состоящий из слов, хочу проверить столбец на вхождение в него этих слов, в случае вхождения - заменить на это слово из списка

Функция создает столбец со старыми названиями и еще ругается:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.

```
def name_compress(row):
    for item in list_data:
    
        if row['object_name'] == '*' + item + '*':
            return item
        else:
            return row['object_name']


data['object_name_1'] = data.apply(name_compress, axis=1)
```

Cписок: `list_data = ['шоколадница', 'макдоналдс', 'kfc']`

```
       id       object_name
0   21894      ресторан kfc
1  148815  кафе макдональдс
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: list_data = ['шоколадница', 'макдоналдс', 'kfc'] - такой список

Comment: воспользуйтесь кнопкой "править" под вопросом, чтобы отредактировать сам вопрос

Comment: @MaxU Исправил вопрос

Comment: `row['object_name'] == '*' + item + '*'` не делает сопоставление с образцом.

Comment: @Евг, вы не привели пример результата, который хотите получить